# Represent process as a thread in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm supposed to implement a very simple version of MPI (or rather simulate the behaviour) in ruby.
Part of the assignment is to create a Communicator class which has
different processes running on different hosts.
To prove the "independency" of the processes two consecutive for loops over the array in which the processes are stored should output them in a different order.

The processes should be represented as either instances of a class I made up or as threads.
For the first part I just created a class which has the required attributes and changed the "each" method to shuffle the process list after each call.

However, I'm stuggling with the second part. For now I've just created a subclass of Thread and added the required attributes and methods. I just create as many instances of my subclass with an infinite loop in the block as needed and store them in an array. 
Now, on looping through the array, the processes seem to have different response times but still are written to console in order.

As I'm in doubt to whether my approach is right or not, I would like to have some suggestions on how the required behaviour could be achieved:

```
for process in communicator write rank

for process in communicator write rank
> 1
> 2
> 3
#####
> 3
> 1
> 2
```

Edit:

The Communicator:

```
class ThreadKomunikator


attr_reader :hosty, :procesy, :rankPool
@@rankPool = (0..100).to_a.reverse

public
def initialize(hosty)

    @procesy = []
    @hosty = hosty
    hosty.each do |name, number|
        for i in 1..number
            tempProc = ThreadProc.new{while true do continue; end;}
            tempProc.init(getRank(),name)
            procesy << tempProc
        end
    end
end

def MPI_Comm_size()
    procesy.length
end

def each
    procesy.each do |proces|
        yield proces
    end
#   #procesy.shuffle!
end

def [](x)
    procesy.each do |proces|
        if proces.rank == x
            return proces.MPI_Get_processor_name()
        end
    end
    return "No process of that rank found!"
end

def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    if hosty.has_key?("#{method}")
        return hosty["#{method}"]
    else
        return 0
    end
end

private 
def getRank
    @@rankPool.pop
end



end
```

The subclass of Thread:

```
class ThreadProc< Thread
attr_accessor :rank, :host
def init(rank, host)
    @rank = rank
    @host = host
end


def MPI_Comm_rank()
    @rank
end

def MPI_Get_processor_name()
    @host
end

end
```

Comment: since you did not post any code, how can we help you?

Comment: I was hoping for a concept first, to figure it out by myself. Or do you think that whole subclassing Thread approach is a good start?